# Discussion: Working TDD in a Scrum context

Tags: tdd, scrum

When I work TDD I tend to start out with the big picture and create the tests that should succeed in order for the overall assignment to be completed - it then kicks off a number of supporting classes/methods/tests as I 'dig in'.

If my assignment has been planned out in detail, I would then open one task, and in order to solve it, open another and then another. Only when the overall tests are succeeding can I close the original task, which means that at any given time, I would have a number of open tasks.

I find that this approach conflict somewhat with the scrum approach where, ideally,  I should be able to take and close a task within a day's work - and never have more than one task open at a time.

I'm looking for input about how you manage this in your project - references to articles are also very welcome, I'm sure this has been debated thoroughly somewhere...

The 'answer tick' will be awarded to best comment/reference.

Thanks for any input,

Anders, Denmark

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask --- [tour]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (Unfortunately, this question is too old to be  migrated.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if your tasks might be horizontally sliced - perhaps along technical boundaries like "create database table" or "write controller" - while your development is sliced vertically.

I hate having to split stories into tasks anyway (it's useful for novice teams and to keep project managers happy, nothing else) but if I'm forced to do so I'll split them vertically, by scenario. Take the first "happy path" through a story. Make that into the first task. Find the edge cases. Each of them becomes another task. So for instance, if I'm asked to write ATM software and the story title is "Let people take out cash", my tasks might be:

- Allow user to take out cash
- Prevent user from taking out cash if he doesn't have enough
- Overdrafts
- Run out of $10
- No money left at all
- User hit their daily cash limit
- Check that it works with Fred's "PIN verification" story.

This has the additional benefit that at any point I can showcase something and get feedback, allowing me to bring testers in early to help me work out if I've missed anything.

Comment: Hi Lunivore,
I think my problem has been exactly as you point out in first paragraph. Point taken and something I'll have in mind for my next sprint.
Thanks

Comment: Great perspective, thanks. Organize by subject matter. This way the end user drives the process, which is why we're doing this in the first place, yes?

Answer (score 0):

I think you approach this maybe in the wrong way. It sounds like your original estimates on work amounts are way off because if they aren't, why not just use the original task? That's still what you are trying to accomplish. If you find that the work amount was very wrong or you misanalyzed the problem, you should, IMO, not just add more and more tasks into your sprint because it doesn't help.

So rather than create just one task, try to create all of the tasks and open only the one you need to start on first. So don't think of the tasks in a top-down manner, rather as parallel tasks.

I might not quite understand your case, though. Of course you often find stuff you hadn't thought of in the middle of doing things, but if you tasks are so big that you regularly over-exceed you estimates badly then my only suggestion is to plan your work better. Just because the backlog has a big task doesn't mean you can't split it up into your spring log.